# Python Exiftool get metadata from livestream

Tags: python, http, live-streaming, exiftool

I am trying to read geotagging data from a live stream online, here is my code:

```
import exiftool

def getVideo(url):
    with exiftool.ExifToolHelper() as et:
        metadata = et.getmetadata(url)
    print(metadata)
    

getVideo("url/to/stream")
```

however, I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Documents\vtest2.py", line 9, in <module>
    getVideo("url/to/stream")
  File "C:\Users\alexa\Documents\vtest2.py", line 4, in getVideo
    with exiftool.ExifToolHelper() as et:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\exiftool\helper.py", line 101, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\exiftool\exiftool.py", line 300, in __init__
    self.executable = executable or constants.DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\exiftool\exiftool.py", line 374, in executable
    raise FileNotFoundError(f'"{new_executable}" is not found, on path or as absolute path')
FileNotFoundError: "exiftool.exe" is not found, on path or as absolute path
```

is there a better way to read metadata from a live stream?

Comment: Did you install exiftool and make sure it's part of the PATH?  The `FileNotFoundError: "exiftool.exe" is not found, on path or as absolute path` is pretty clear that your script can't find exiftool.

Comment: I did that, I am now getting this new error:
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\exiftool\helper.py", line 136, in execute
    raise ExifToolExecuteError(self._last_status, self._last_stdout, self._last_stderr, str_bytes_params)
exiftool.exceptions.ExifToolExecuteError: execute returned a non-zero exit status: 1

Comment: I don't know anything about the Python exiftool lib, but exiftool does not have the ability to read a URL.  So if the lib doesn't have the ability to open an URL, you would have to use something else to download that and you would then pass the stream through a pipe.  See the cURL example under [exiftool piping examples](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#PIPING-EXAMPLES).